# onclick event inside a button

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have this HTML structure:

```
<button onclick="console.log('blih');">
    <div style="padding:20px; border: 1px solid black" onclick="console.log('blah');">Test</div>
    Test 2
 </button>
```

This always only fires the button `onclick` when clicked, even inside the "Test" zone. How can I get it to fire the div's `onclick` ?

I have the problem on Firefox, this works fine on Chrome and Safari.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ovr0w9w4/

Comment: A div inside a button is not valid html.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/the-button-element.html#the-button-element says that a `<button>` must contain only Phrasing content.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. (the codebase is not from me..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't work consistently, because [it's not valid to have a `<div>` in a `<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Summary).

You can fake a button though.

```css
.btn {
  border: 1px solid black; 
  border-radius: 2px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0.2em;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.btn:active {
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
}

.btn > div {
  padding:20px; 
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn" onclick="console.log('blih');">
    <div onclick="console.log('blah');">Test</div>
    Test 2
 </div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did in the end. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of invalid html you could simply use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and add `btn` class to your first `<div>`.

```
<div id="div1" class="btn btn-default">
  <div id="div2">
  </div>
</div>
```

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/co5sm0d6/